# What will be the explicit formula for Shifted Legendre's polynomial in interval $x\in[a,b]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, approximation, legendre-polynomials

If I defined shifted Legendre polynomial $\tilde P_{n}(x)=P_{n}(\frac{2x-b-a}{b-a})  for\;all x\in[a,b]$ Then what will be the explicit formula $P_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} (-1)^{n+k} \frac{(n+k)!}{(n-k)! (k!)^{2}}x^{k}$ for $\tilde P_{n}(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

**QUICK ANSWER**, too long for a comment, made CW.

Let $y=\frac{2x-b-a}{b-a}$, so $\tilde{P}_n(x)=P_n(y)$. You have $\tilde{P}_n(x)=P_n(y)=\sum (\text{something})y^k=\sum (\text{something})\left(\frac{2x-b-a}{b-a}\right)^k$.

Of course this is a power series in $x-\frac{b-a}{2}$.

Comment: As per my observation the power series should be in the form of $\sum something (\frac {(x-a)^{k}}{b^{k}})$ as if we take the interval $[0,T]$ that is $\tilde P_{n}(x)=P_{n}(\frac {2x}{T}-1)$the power series is of the form $\sum something (\frac {x^{k}}{T^{k}})$. But  don't know how to proceed it and what will be the exact formula.

Comment: @PratimaTiwari: I don't understand your question. What do you mean by "proceed it"? And I disagree with your remarks. You get a power series in $(x-T/2)^k$. Maybe you want a series in $x^k$? Then it is not a straightforward computation. You can expand $(x-T/2)^k$ using the binomial theorem for $\lvert x \rvert <T/2$, but then you have to sum a double series.